# When to use a question mark for XML attributes?

Tags: android, xml, xml-attribute

Some XML attributes need to start its value with a question mark (`?`) and I just wondering how can I know these attributes, particularly these attributes, aren't shown when I press on ( CTRL + Space ) to show suggested attributes 
examples of these attributes:

- `android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"`
- `android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"`

Comment: maybe slow a little bit down on the title... less text is easier to read. just fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `?` is for referencing style attributes; the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ResourcesFromXml) explains it:

> To reference a style attribute, the name syntax is almost identical to the normal resource format, but instead of the at-symbol (`@`), use a question-mark (`?`), and the resource type portion is optional.

```
?[<package_name>:][<resource_type>/]<resource_name>
```